# css3 simple animation, when hovering off of the element, it doesn't animate, it just snaps back. How to make it animate smoothly back?

Tags: css, css-animations

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/vX7CV/10/

This is a simple example, but for what I need this for, transition will not work, animation needs to be used.

When hovering the element, the animation smoothly animates the element, when hovering off of the element it snaps back to it's original settings without smoothly animating back.

Is there a way to cause it to animate back to it's settings instead of snapping back like it is?

Animate needs to be used for the :hover event, but when hovering off the element, I could use transition, if this would work, I can't get it to work though.

Comment: CSS transitions are not CSS animations.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested you version in Google Chrome and it worked fine for me.
Also added in the Firefox compatibility and that also worked fine for me.

Here is what I have now:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    </li>test</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}
@-moz-keyframes flow-down {   
    0% {
      padding-bottom: 0%;
    }
    100% {
      padding-bottom: 30%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flow-down {   
    0% {
      padding-bottom: 0%;
    }
    100% {
      padding-bottom: 30%;
    }
}
ul:hover {
    -moz-animation-name: flow-down;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-name: flow-down;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

And here is the JSFiddle version just incase:

http://jsfiddle.net/NQ5xk/1/

Hope this helps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

in firefox, if you have change 'position' or 'z-index' attr during the animation, animation will not run